# ERROR : Guzzle Will not follow more than 1 redirects Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, server, guzzle

i want to ask something confusing,

i had guzzle script in drupal 8 like this

```
      $client = \Drupal::service('http_client');
      $getUserInfo = $client->get($this->url, [
                                    'Accept' => 'application/json', 
                                    'auth' => [
                                               $this->authUsername, 
                                               $this->authPassword
                                              ]
                                   ]);
      $resultUser = json_decode($getUserInfo->getBody());
```

i get error like this
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDcbx.png)

but this is weird sometime this error missing but sometime it was appear, i dont know what is happen

and not just in that script but in every Guzzle request

i try

- increase the maximum redirect to 1000 but its not work
- disabled guzzle redirect but its stil not work

my analys

- i test the API with POSTMAN everything is fine
- and i had project with laravel in same server with the same API and its work

its just happen in drupal project in that server,
but in another server its fine

may someone had a same problem

Please advise

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to increase maximum redirects?

```
$client->get($this->url, [
    'headers' => [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
    'auth' => [
        $this->authUsername,
        $this->authPassword
    ],
    'allow_redirects' => [
        'max' => 5,
    ]
]);
```

P.S. Also you have a mistake with `'Accept'`: it should be inside the `'headers'` container.

Comment: i've add like that before but it just redirect as much as the max value
if i add max => 1000 it just loop 1000 redirect

Comment: Then, if in Postman it works fine, try to set the browser's User-Agent (some sites make decisions based on it) and maybe other headers that Postman sends. I've had such a issue because of the headers.